# modifying access permissions from an abstract class in the derived class

Tags: c#, properties, abstract-class

So I have an abstract class called AbstactSearchWithTwoLevelCache that was provided to me. All of its abstract properties only have read access (with a get;). I am not permitted to add a set; to the those abstract properties. Is there a way to change this in the derived class, SearchWithTwoLevelCache? In other words, is there a way to set these properties in the derived class?

Comment: Also look at this one: [Override abstract readonly property to read/write property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489361/override-abstract-readonly-property-to-read-write-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mark the property with `new`, you define a new property, like this:

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    public int Property
    {
        get { ... }
    }
}

class NewClass : BaseClass
{
    public new int Property
    {
        get { return base.Property; }
        set { ... }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

The above works if the property in the base class is not `abstract`. When it is abstract, this will not work since you need to implement it. One option you do have is to create a class in between, like this:

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract int Property { get; }
}

class Between : BaseClass
{
    public override int Property
    {
        get { ... }
    }
}

class NewClass : Between
{
    public new int Property
    {
        get { return base.Property; }
        set { ... }
    }
}
```

This however in no way is an elegant solution. Then, the real answer becomes that you cannot really do this (at least not without the above work around).

Comment: Sorry, misread your question. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine a way you can override them directly.  Indirectly when you override the abstract class properties, the Getters can retrieve from a private field, and then you can create new properties that have Setters that set those fields.

Kind of a rig I know.  Maybe there is a more elegant way around this.